# BibTeX : what is in 3rd arg of ENTRY?

Tags: bibtex

Could someone explain meaning of parameters is 3rd argument of the `ENTRY` declaration that appear in some BST files? Here is small extract from `unsrtnat.bst`:

```
ENTRY
  { address
    annote
    . . .
  }
  {}
  { label extra.label sort.label short.list }
```

I guess that `label`, `extra.label`, `sort.label`, `short.list` are computed by `bibtex.exe` but how? The `label` parameter seems to be ordinal number of current reference. Where one could find complete description of the `ENTRY` command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ENTRY` function takes three arguments

1. External string variables - usually the fields
2. Internal integer variables - usually empty
3. Internal string variables - usually the label and so forth

These are all variables associated with each entry separately, rather than variables used in the process of calculations. So you need to declare a variable here for each field you want to work with.

In the case of external variables, the list given for `ENTRY` defines which fields are read from the `.bib` file. On the other hand, the internal variables have to be calculated somewhere in the `.bst` file. For example, in `unsrtnat.bst` you will find

```
FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ calc.short.authors
  short.list
  "("
  *
  year duplicate$ empty$
  short.list key field.or.null = or
     { pop$ "" }
     'skip$
  if$
  *
  'label :=
}
```

which is itself called by

```
FUNCTION {presort}
{ calc.label
  label sortify
  "    "
  *
  seq.num #1 + 'seq.num :=
  seq.num  int.to.fix
  'sort.label :=
  sort.label *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {presort}
```

Notice that just defining the function does not do anything: it is only because `ITERATE` is used that `label` is calculated.

There is more on BibTeX in the document [*Tame the BeaST*](http://ctan.org/pkg/tamethebeast)